# Reliable Upload-App (FTP/WebDAV/...) for Android

Tags: android, file-synchronization, ftp, uploader, webdav

Sometimes I need to upload large files (from mobile locations) and my idea is that I can copy the files to my android phone and let it do the work of uploading the files without monitoring the progress. The phone itself is connected via WiFi, but the connection's reliability may vary. The uploader can be totally simple in terms of "browse files, select files to upload and just do it" or "sync all files in this directory (but one-way only upload, no download)", but it must be very robust. If the WiFi signal goes away or the connection is interrupted for any other reason, the uploader must continue to retry and resume uploads as soon as the connection becomes available again.

The uploader can work with FTP/WebDAV/SCP. (Preferably encrypted (FTPS/WebDAVs).

Answer (score 1):

As you write synchronisation is an option, **[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)** might be a good choice. It supports a load of different protocols. You define "folder pairs" (which directory on your Android device should be synchronized with which directory on the server), whether the synchronization should be unidirectional (only upload / only download) or bidirectional (both), plus some other options – and the app takes care for the rest. Synchronisation can be triggered manually, or on schedule; with the paid version, you can also have *Tasker* trigger it.

[image: FolderSync] [image: FolderSync Accounts] [image: Folderpairs]
<sup>*FolderSync* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm using the paid version myself and am quite satisfied with it. However, I have no experiences with "flaky WiFi signals" as you describe. IMHO if the connection breaks before the sync was completed, it simply goes into "failed" state. But if you set it to be scheduled, the next run should continue where the failed one stopped.